# How to open subwindows after each other in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

I'm trying to open few windows one after the other in `tkinter`. They are closing itself after set amount of time. Creating first window breaks my loop (it doesn't even reach `print` instruction). What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Subwindow:

    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time
        self.window = tk.Toplevel()
        self.window.geometry("300x300+1000+200")
        self.window.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        tk.Label(self.window, text=time).pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.update_time()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def update_time(self):
        if self.time:
            self.window.title(str(self.time))
            self.time -= 1
            self.window.after(1000, self.update_time)
        else:
            self.window.destroy()

class Window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.initialize()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def initialize(self):
        buttons = tk.Frame(self.window)
        tk.Button(self.window, text="Start", width=5, command=self.start).pack(in_=buttons, side="left")
        tk.Button(self.window, text="Exit", width=5, command=self.close).pack(in_=buttons, side="left")
        buttons.place(relx=0.97, rely=0.95, anchor=tk.SE)

    def close(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        quit()

    def start(self):
        for x in [5,10,15]:
            sub = Subwindow(x)
            print(x)

Window()
```

Explain me please how can I fix it to get them opening one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `mainloop` more than once. Remove the call to `mainloop` inside `Subwindow.__init__`.